# Can I say 'crucial figures'?

Tags: word-usage

I want to write 'crucial figures in english literature' to not write 'important figures in english literature'. Can I use word 'crucial' in this case?

Comment: What are you trying to express about these figures?  Definitions of "crucial" usually say something like "of great importance" or "very important."  Is there a reason why those definitions may not be what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but "crucial" has a much stronger connotation. It means that the person was *necessary*, not just important. "English literature" is a very, very broad field, so I would be hard-pressed to think of people that all of English literature would not exist without. It's not impossible to write a sentence in which that makes sense, though.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was just looking for some... less simple and usual word for 'important', but crucial is maybe too strong. Thanks for help

Comment: If you narrowed it down, you could use the word "crucial." For example, instead of English literature, you could specify English sonnets, in which case the sentence "Shakespeare was crucial to the development of English sonnets" would be appropriate. Without Shakespeare, not too many would consider "English sonnets" a particular genre, since the form originated in Italy. Others came before him, too; they were also crucial.

Answer (score 1):

Though the use of the adjective crucial for a person isn't common,  think you can use "crucial figures" for persons who are unusually important in a field such as Shakespeare is a crucial figure in English literature.

You normally use the 'crucial' for something that's extremely important because everything else depents on it.  For example, a crucial role, moment, factor, issue, decision, etc.

Crucial is really a very strong word in terms of its meaning.  I think you can say key figures instead.